# How is it possible to have different aspect ratio than physical resolution?

Tags: h.264, libavcodec

I have this movie that is in 4:3 ratio. The properties clearly say 1920x1440, however, what's puzzling me is the Video codec below. The actual played video indeed has dimensions of 1920x1440 as seen in the screenshot.

> H.264/AVC 1920x1080 (4:3)

What does it mean and how is that possible?
What is the actual resolution of the media file?

[image: MPC:BE]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several terms defining aspect ratios in a video stream like [Pixel Aspect Ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_aspect_ratio) (**PAR**), [Display Aspect Ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect_ratio_(image)) (**DAR**), [Storage Aspect Ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storage_aspect_ratio) (**SAR**).

And yes, video might encode **non-square pixels**, in which case you may see disparity as in your case, when physical resolution of the video has `1920x1080` dimensions (`16:9` aspect ratio), but displayed at different proportions (`4:3` in your case). I don't know why player (which one?) shows `1920x1440` - I guess it is an internal implementation detail of a particular video player stretching an input video into a larger resolution to show it with designed proportions; another video player would do this in a different way.

Non-square pixels were very common in [DVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD-Video) times due to limitations of hardware of that time. Nowadays, such video streams occur very rarely.